# grafana parse data from Templating parameter

Tags: sql, regex, templating, grafana

I have query :

```
SELECT mean($Parameters) FROM "meter" WHERE "macid" =~ /^$macid$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY  time($interval), "macid" fill(none)
```

where $Parameters is templating value.
value of $Parameters  is  "Description (field)"

[image: screenshot example]

but I need to use not complete value of $Parameters but just information in bracket ('field' in that case)

Is there a way to parse this information from Templating value in grafana?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `"Description (field)"` anywhere completely?

If not, enter `/\(([^)]+)\)/` in the regex field where you're setting up your templating variable and you should only see `field` as the templated value.